# How can I use reflection to set this object's property?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reflection, aspose

I have an external library I am using, namely *Aspose.Email.dll* (available on *NuGet*). It has a `PageInfo` class. *Go To Definition* shows the following for it in *Visual Studio*:

```
using System;

namespace Aspose.Email
{
    public class PageInfo
    {
        protected PageInfo next;

        public int AbsoluteOffset { get; }
        public int ItemsPerPage { get; }
        public bool LastPage { get; }
        public virtual PageInfo NextPage { get; }
        public int PageOffset { get; }
        public int TotalCount { get; }
    }
}
```

Long story short, I need to create a *PageInfo* object. How can I create one using Reflection and also set its `ItemsPerPage` property?

I have tried this:

```
var result = (PageInfo)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(PageInfo));
typeof(PageInfo).GetProperty("ItemsPerPage", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).SetValue(result, 1);
```

The problem is that `SetValue` errors out with `Property set method not found.`

Comment: What are you doing that you need to create a `PageInfo`? Perhaps if you ask a new question about *"How can I do X without crateing my own PageInfo?"* you may have a solution better than using reflection.

Comment: I was afraid someone might ask. I am programming an abstract interface library to consolidate two different mail libraries I am using together (this and the Exchange library) I am trying to consolidate a way of paging data between the two. Unfortunately a big caveat with this IMAP library is that you can't really build an arbitrary paging query, but must always use a linked paging object after you first make a call to get paged data. Its because of the nature of the library and how its API was implemented that it becomes a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getter-only properties do not have setters. They use a `readonly` backing field that can only be set in the constructor.

You can change the properties to have private setter, e.g.

```
public int ItemsPerPage { get; private set; }
```

If you do not have access to the code, you can find the matching field using `GetField` and set its value.

```
typeof(PageInfo).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredFields
    .First(f => f.Name.Contains("ItemsPerPage")).SetValue(result, 1);
```

Comment: Can't change the library as I don't have the source, so I can't edit the `ItemsPerPage` property.

Comment: Checking the library using *dotPeek*, and also enumerating through the `DeclaredFields`...I am at a bit of an impass, because...their named fields contain names such as `#=qOeu6uj6DPtGwJ1qAj8pvJQ==` and `#=qQACP_gKR9skNS8JCd3aPRw==`, leading me to believe they are hashing them or something for each version of the library, which sucks because upgrade-ability goes out the window...

Comment: What do you mean when you say to grab the field name from the getter and use it? Oh, you mean just use the named fields like `#=qOeu6uj6DPtGwJ1qAj8pvJQ==`?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that. I guess there's no other way huh? I will park the issue for now then...

Comment: It's not a sealed class, so can you create your subclass of PageInfo, and override that ItemsPerPage property using the 'new' keyword?  public new int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }  ??

Comment: You're right, I was hoping maybe the method you were trying to call took a PageInfo object as a parameter. I think you should try a new email library :)